# Use Button to Add Variables and Return Number in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui, uibutton

**Edit: This is the latest of everything I have tried. I've moved my variables out of the body view and the func out of the button action. I will continue to update this as I move along until either someone posts an answer or I manage to figure this out on my own. I feel like I am close to solving this. Just not sure what the last piece of the puzzle is.**

**Edit: I just realized that I didn't need to multiply. I need to add the two together. Also updated the code to what I currently have in there that I have tried. Thank you again.**

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is the addition of two variables. One variable already has a number in it, the other is grabbing from a text field. Below is the code that I have:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BaseOGIntView: View {
  
    @StateObject var equation = BOIEquations()

    let sublotSampTons = BOIEquations.shared.sublotSampTons
    let storedRanSampTons = BOIEquations.shared.ranSampTons

    func sublotTonnage(_ number: Double) -> Double {
        let number = sublotSampTons + storedRanSampTons
        return number
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section{
                    Text("Random Number: \(BOIEquations.shared.randomNumber, specifier: "%.3f")")
                }
                Section {
                    Text("Sublot Tons: \(storedRanSampTons, specifier: "%.0f")")
                    TextField("Sublot Tons", value: $equation.sublotSampTons, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                    Button(action: {
                    }) {
                        Text("Generate Random Sample")
                    }
                }
                Text("Random Sample Tonnage: ")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BaseOGIntView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BaseOGIntView()
    }
}
```

When you click the button that say "Generate Random Sample", it should add the two variables ($equation.sublotSampTons & storedRanSampTons) and return that up to sublotTonnage to be displayed in the "Random Sample Tonnage:" text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this seems to be the last step I need in the process of making this work. Once the multiplication is done and returns a number, I just have to have that number show up in the final spot "Random Sample Tonnage:

**Edit** I should also add that $equation.sublotSampTons seems to be a BindingDouble according to the errors I am getting...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A SwiftUI View is a struct (value type), it could be created multiples, so declaring any variables would have the lifetime of the view. Please could you read the fundamentals of SwiftUI or watch Apple Developer videos on it.